# How to get children from element?

Tags: c++, winapi, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I have my element in `IUIAutomationElement elem` , and now i want to get its children,

for that, i have tried following this code

```
IUIAutomationElement* dummy = NULL;     //creating a dummy
IUIAutomationElementArray* children_array;   //creating an array 
elem->GetCachedChildren(&children_array); 
children_array->GetElement(0,&dummy);
qDebug() << dummy;
```

it doesnt work and i get unhandled exceptions. where am i going wrong ?

Comment: What exception? Maybe children_array is simply empty.

Comment: @SimonMourier it definitely has some elements. getting Unhandled exception, and here i am creating a variable `dummy` and i assume that the element at 0th position in `children_array` will be stored in `dummy` , when i do this `children_array->GetElement(0,&dummy);`

Comment: Please add error checking for each function call to see if there is function failure before this "*unhandled exceptions*".

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT, changed it , now i dont get exceptions but still no children name

Comment: @Danzow `get_CurrentName` succeed but `child_name` is empty?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT, i have tried it on some elements who definately have children , i dunno if i am doing something wrong in code

Comment: Is `number` zero?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT, it is not , i hardcoded a different value but still not getting.

Comment: User `elem->FindAll(TreeScope_Children, trueCondition, &children_array)` instead of GetCachedChildren (and yes, IUIAutomationElementArray can be null if it contains nothing, which is a bit weird in terms of COM usual rules...). use `automation->CreateTrueCondition(&trueCondition)` to create an unconditional true condition. PS: call SysFreeString on child_name or it's a memory leak.

Comment: @SimonMourier, Thanks, i am now using `FindAll `instead of `GetCachedChildren`, i have question about `automation->CreateTrueCondition(&trueCondition)` , here is automation a `IUIAutomation* ` type ?? , i have posted the code above in Update, still not getting output ? am i going wrong somewhere

Comment: Now it is working,, Thank you guys , actually before i was not using Treescope correctly. now i guess i dont have any memory leaks

Comment: @Danzow You can share your solution as an answer which will help others are searching on similar issue.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT, will do , Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i was able to solve it like this , i forgot to set the true condition, and here instead of using `GetCachedChildren()` , i am using `FindAll()`, as this serves the purpose better.

````
IUIAutomationElementArray* children_array = NULL;
                            IUIAutomationElement* single_elem = nullptr;
                            TreeScope treeScope_1 = TreeScope::TreeScope_Children;

                            IUIAutomationCondition* Condition;
                            automation->CreateTrueCondition(&Condition);

                            HRESULT hs = elem->FindAll(treeScope_1, Condition, &children_array);
                           // HRESULT hs = elem->GetCachedChildren(&children_array);
                            if (SUCCEEDED(hs) && children_array != NULL) {
                                int number = 0;
                                children_array->get_Length(&number);
                                for (int i = 0;i < number;i++)
                                {
                                    children_array->GetElement(i, &single_elem);
                                    if (single_elem != NULL)
                                    {
                                        BSTR child_name = NULL;
                                        hs = single_elem->get_CurrentName(&child_name);
                                        if (SUCCEEDED(hs) && child_name != NULL)
                                        {
                                            std::wstring child_ws(child_name, SysStringLen(child_name));
                                            QString child_qstring = QString::fromStdWString(child_ws);
                                            global_ui->xml_scripts_textbox->addItem(child_qstring);
                                            qDebug() << child_qstring;
                                        }
                                        SysFreeString(child_name);
                                    }
                                    single_elem = NULL;
                                }
                                SAFE_RELEASE(children_array);
                            }
                       ```
````